# Assign a single column name to a r data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Please pardon my ignorance ,Since i am beginner in R

In R i am transposing a dataframe (certain rows to columns)  and saving the result back to a data frame which is exactly what i need .
But the column name for the 1st column is missing which i need to join it with other data frames .

Data frame result and function used

```
dish_pair<-as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(count~primary_id+subcategory_name, dishes))
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peyoH.png)

But How can i get the 1st column name as primary_id
which are holding row values  50792 ,50793

(I just need the 1st column name value as primary_id ,renaming data frame values are correct)

Comment: Thanks for comment but ur provided steps didn't helped
here is the output

`> dish_pair$primary_id <- rownames(dish_pair)
> View(dish_pair)
> head(dish_pair)
                Beef Chicken Coffee Deserts Dessert Drinks Fish  
50792   15     190     19      33      54          21         67       12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column on the picture is just the row names. You need to add it to the data frame and give the column a name:

```
 dish_pair <- data.frame(primary_id=rownames(dish_pair), dish_pair)
```

Comment: Hello @Marcelo ,
Thnx for comment i tired as suggested above but it didn't worked
it renamed the 1st column to primary_id  
`> colnames(dish_pair)[1]<-c('primary_id')
 >head(dish_pair)
`                   primary_id Chicken Coffee Deserts 
*50792         15                190           19         33          
*
But  needed was                                                                                                                                                  `primary_id    Beef        Chicken Coffee Deserts 
50792           15             190           19         33      `

Comment: @AnkitKhanduri, Updated the answer.